# Resizing Mfc dialog with embeded QWinWidget

Tags: qt, qt-mfc-migration

I asked my question on qt centre forum, but no answer yet.
Hope someone will know something about this.

I have an Mfc dialog with QWinWidget inside it. 
When I resize my dialog I want my QWinWidget to automatically
be resized and repositioned as well. This is the code that creates the QWinWidget inside the mfc dialog:

```
int MyCDialog::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
   if (CDialog::OnCreate( lpCreateStruct ) == -1 )
            return -1;
    win=new QWinWidget( this->m_hWnd );
        MyFrame * dialog=new MyFrame(win);   
    win->move(0,0);     
    win->show(); 
    return 0;
}
```

MyFrame is derived from QFrame object. The QFrame object is made
with Qt designer. QFrame has assigned layout, which supposes to do geometrical management of QFrame child widgets.

Here is the code that executes when I drag the resizing border of my dialog:

```
void MyCDailog::OnSize(UINT nType,int cx,int cy)
{
   QObjectList list=win->children();
   QFrame* p=(QFrame*) list.at(0);
   p->resize(QSize(cx,cy));
}
```

When the dialog is resized I am calling the resize method of my frame object from OnSize, and I was expecting that after I do resize to the frame, the frame should resize and reposition its child widgets according to their size hint and size polices. But this is not happening, at least not as it should. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Frame does have its children in a layout, right? And there is Qt event loop running?

Comment: @Eugene: I think missing an event loop would do this, but I can't imagine the drawing would work at all without an event loop, so I think we would have seen a different question had that been a problem.

Comment: Actually I am using qt mfc migration solution, and that merges the loop of my mfc application with qt message loop. And yes , frame have its children widgets in layout. I think I solved the problem . The problem was that I didnot have set layot for QWinWidget,  although I don't understand why it is aproblem at all.